# Windows 7 Backup and Restore is not seeing all partitions of my hard drive 

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

I want to use Windows 7's Backup and Restore functionality to create a backup system image which backs up ALL partitions on my computer. Currently I have 4 partitions on my system (with their specifics given as well, which were taken from Disk Management). They appear in this order in Disk Management as well (optical drives are not shown):

Recovery Partition --> no volume name mentioned, no file system mentioned, no drive letter assigned, Status: Healthy (Recovery Partition)

C: --> Contains Windows 7, Status: Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Logical Drive)

D: --> Contains Windows XP (as a backup OS), Status: Healthy (Logical Drive)

System Reserved --> no drive letter assigned, Status: Health (System, Active, Primary Partition)

My problem is Backup and Restore doesn't list the very first Recovery Partition is being one of the partitions it can include in a system image .. Only the last 3 partitions are shown .. How can I make Backup and Restore also include the very first Recovery partition in its system image as well .. ??

Also, I went ahead an made a system image just to check how many VHDs were made, just in case a VHD was made for the Recovery partition as well .. Its wasnt .. Only three VHDs were made for the last 3 partitions listed above ..

Comment: The recovery partition isn't necessary to recover your system. It's just a small partition which mirrors some of the functionality of a recovery DVD.

Comment: You would need a 3rd party software to do a full disc image....http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp